How to avoid explicit return types for getters in Pinia with TypeScript?
I'm using Pinia for state management in my Vue.js project with TypeScript, and I want to simplify the return type definitions for my getters. Here's a basic example of what I have:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

// Define state interface
type State = {
  count: number;
  name: string;
}

export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: (): State => ({
    count: 0,
    name: 'Counter',
  }),

  getters: {
    // Simple getter returning count
    getCount: (state) => state.count,

    // Getter using another getter
    // I cannot use an arrow function because `this`
    // would not point to the other getter. As a result,
    // a return type is required.
    message(state): string {
      return `${this.getCount} - ${state.name}`;
    },
  }
});

Is there a way to avoid explicitly defining the return types for each getter in Pinia, especially when one getter depends on another? I'm looking for a method to simplify the type management in my store.

To simplify the type management for getters in your Pinia store, you can use TypeScript's utility types to infer types dynamically. Here’s how you can refactor your store code to leverage type inference and reduce explicit type definitions for each getter:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

type WrapInFunction<S, T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (state: S) => T[K];
};

// Define state interface
type State = {
  count: number;
  name: string;
}

// Define getters interface
type Getters = WrapInFunction<State, {
  getCount: number;
  message: string
}>

export const useCounterStore = defineStore<'counter', State, Getters>('counter', {
  state: (): State => ({
    count: 0,
    name: 'Counter',
  }),

  getters: {
    // Simple getter returning count
    getCount: (state) => state.count,

    // Getter using another getter
    message(state) {
      return `${this.getCount} - ${state.name}`;
    },
  }
});


I'd like to have a better way, but this way it's more verbose and that's all, getter types aren't inferred from return types

It is a bit verbose, unfortunately, I wish Pinia had this built in... But it's the best I could come up with
